# Eliminate lines based on values in multiple columns

Tags: awk, sed, filter

I'm trying to remove rows from a big table but conditioned that one column has one value and another column has other values.

So far I've been trying this but I guess I'm not combining the awk properly..

```
awk '$11 !="1"'| awk '$20==2 || $20==3' infile.txt >out.txt
```

The code is probably too simple but should work anyways..or not?

Thanks

edit:

This is what the table looks like

```
    5306083 TGATCAATCTCATAAC[A/C]AAAAAAAAA  consensus_24    211 1   species 0   0   0   T   0   7   T   recommended 0.708   F   0   -100    T   recommended
    5193751 AGTAGCTTGCGCGGA[C/T]GGGGGGGGG   consensus_32    227 1   species 0   0   0   T   1   1   T   not_recommended 0.75    F   0   -100    T   not_recommended
    5193254 TAAAAAAAAAAAAAA[G/T]ATTCATCC    consensus_26    192 1   species 0   0   0   T   1   0   T   not_recommended 0.726   F   0   -100    T   neutral
```

So if I filter based in that $11=1 and $20  needs to be "neutral" or "not_recommended" I would get this

```
       5306083  TGATCAATCTCATAAC[A/C]AAAAAAAAA  consensus_24    211 1   species 0   0   0   T   0   7   T   recommended 0.708   F   0   -100    T   recommended
```

Comment: You definitely won't remove lines from in file, I think here you will leave in file untouched and write some lines to out-file.

Comment: Your first awk is missing a file input,  also you don't need to invoke awk twice.  See the answer below.

Comment: Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins ASAP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '$11!=1 && ($20==2 || $20==3)' infile.txt > out.txt
```

should do.

UPDATE: based on the input given, you should get two lines in the output for this condition

```
$ awk '$11==1 && ($20=="not_recommended" || $20=="neutral")' file

5193751 AGTAGCTTGCGCGGA[C/T]GGGGGGGGG   consensus_32    227 1   species 0   0   0   T   1   1   T   not_recommended 0.75    F   0   -100    T   not_recommended
5193254 TAAAAAAAAAAAAAA[G/T]ATTCATCC    consensus_26    192 1   species 0   0   0   T   1   0   T   not_recommended 0.726   F   0   -100    T   neutral
```

But I guess, what you mean is you want the negation of this which is different from your original post

```
$ awk '$11!=1 || ($20!="not_recommended" && $20!="neutral")' file

5306083 TGATCAATCTCATAAC[A/C]AAAAAAAAA  consensus_24    211 1   species 0   0   0   T   0   7   T   recommended 0.708   F   0   -100    T   recommended
```

Comment: In this case. you could simplify slightly with a regex; `$20==2 || $20==3` could be written `$20 ~ /^[23]$/`.

Comment: Not working for me.. The outfile is empty. The idea is to remove those lines and get the table without them as output..

Comment: please post a sample input and expected output so that the scripts can be tested.

Comment: Mhmm I see what you mean.. I didnt know I had to add the ! expression to all of them. Thanks a lot. It seems to be working now